# Как получить доступ к ячейкам в Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

При написание скрипта не получается достать значение ячейки гугл таблиц в Google Apps Script. Документацию не осилен, но очень сильно старался.

Comment: Я не сварщик, но возможно вам поможет этот метод: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer). Не забудьте вызвать getValue() если вам нужно значение ячейки.

Comment: Ну и если вам надо функцию на текущую ячейку вызвать ее можно просто параметром прокинуть

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос, конечно, не соответствует требованиям ресурса. Но так как нас тут мало, то нужно отвечать всем.
Попробуйте почитать описание ярлыка [google-apps-script](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), а также вы можете получить ответ на интересующий вас вопрос [1. Google Apps Script. Начало. Нужны они вам или нет?](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h9OISgBtupWSwcz9Nz_GXJTwO2o6bSpyk3muEvQRYSc/edit?usp=sharing)

Остается только процитировать [справку](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer))

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");

// В методе getCell(1,1) используются относительные значения строк и колонок
// В данном случае они будут указывать на ячейку B2
var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
Logger.log(cell.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Берем Таблицу - из нее Ячейку, а дальше значение ("Принцип Кащеева сердца").

`var dt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  .getSheetByName("WeekForm")
  .getRange("J5")
  .getValue();`